# Flask upload to s3 using asyncio

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, boto3, python-asyncio

I am trying to upload a file to s3 using boto3 and the upload instruction falls inside of Flask route

is there a way to keep the s3 file from uploading and have the function return the json without having to do an `await`

```
@jobs.route("/", methods=["POST"])
def process_video():
   
    file = request.files['file']
    logger.info("uploaded file into process %s" % (file.filename,))
    filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
    file_name = os.path.join(UPLOAD_FOLDER, filename)
    file.save(file_name)
    retvalue = await upload_file(filename, 's3-bucket') # here i would not like to await
    return "{\"hello\": \"world demo\"}"


async def upload_file(file_name, bucket, object_name=None):
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    try:
        object_name = file_name
        response = s3_client.upload_file(file_name, bucket, object_name)
        logger.info(response)
    except ClientError as e:
        logging.error(e)
        return False
    return True
```

Comment: Nothing in your code is asynchronous. Remove `async` from `upload_file` and then you won’t need `await`.

Comment: my question was how to return the Flask response while making an upload to s3 still in progress @dirn

Comment: @DevZer0 a common way would be to do the upload in a background job. `Celery` and `rq` are some popular ones for python.

Comment: Can the line `file.save(file_name)` be made async in Flask?

Answer (score 0):

Use `asyncio.create_task()` instead of `await`.

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).